# scrolling images is not moving flat?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I use this simple code to scrolling backgrounds.

```
back1=[CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"back1.jpg"];
        back2=[CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"back2.jpg"];

        CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
        back1.position = ccp(size.width/2, size.height/2);
        back2.position = ccp(size.width/2, (size.height/2)*3);

         [self schedule:@selector(scroll:)];

        [spriteNode addChild:back1];
        [spriteNode addChild:back2];
```

//method

```
-(void)scroll:(ccTime)dt
{
    CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    back1.position = ccp( back1.position.x  , back1.position.y - 99*dt );
    back2.position = ccp( back2.position.x  , back2.position.y - 99*dt );

    if (back1.position.y < -size.height/2) 
    {
        back1.position = ccp(size.width/2, -5+(size.height/2)*3);
    }
    else if (back2.position.y < -size.height/2)
    {
        back2.position = ccp(size.width/2, -5+(size.height/2)*3);
    }


}
```

it DOES works but it doesnt seems natural ,its not moving continuously -if you look close you see its kind of flicking sometimes.
it seems that the fps performance are downed due to this.

this method is "profesional"?  its recommended ? or parallex scrolling is better ?
how can i improve the movement to be "flat" and look good and nature ?

thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Experiment specifying an interval on your schedule, see if you can reach conditions where the selector will be invoked with a reasonable steady state:

```
[self schedule:@selector(scroll:) interval:.05f];
```

would give you (in ideal conditions) 20 moves per second. CCLOG the dt, to see if it is constant.

Comment: thanks i did what you said, it does seems better, but dt is 0.6/0.8/ 0.5 and not const. what does it mean, this method is good for performance anyway ? or should i use other way for that ?

Comment: hard for me to give you a good answer on that ... obtaining a stable enough time base has been a real challenge in one of my games, too much stuff going on in different threads sometimes starves my 'schedules'. As I said, you must experiment with it, and figure out what is resource intensive (cpu, graphics) that could interfere with the scheduler, then try to mitigate somehow their effects.

Answer (score 0):

I use actions for this, check the following post with the code i used for something similar to what you need. Is an old code and i'm sure there is a better way to do that but it works

[Cocos2D: Gap in scrolling background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276739/cocos2d-gap-in-scrolling-background)

Comment: thanks a lot but i have tried moving with actions. same thing. its not looking REAL, it kind of flicking sometimes.